# How to use large float numbers?

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate 9999999999x999999.
when I try in normal float,result not answers the number.I see some apps can calculate large numbers.
please help me
**Edit:** 
How I change number"12.0" to "12"?

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` or `double` depending on your needs

Comment: Edit: the numbers is in edittext

Comment: @amirmamed So what's the issue about that? Get the number from the `EditText` using `getText().toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `BigDecimal` class, keep in mind that you should always create from a `String` if you want consistent behaviour (and don't want to read up that much about the documentation).

Consider you have two input `String`s:

```
String in1 = "9999999999";
String in2 = "999999";
```

Then you can create `BigDecimal`s out of them:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(in1);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(in2);
```

Then calculate the resulting answer:

```
BigDecimal answer = bd1.multiply(bd2);
```

Then retrieve the answer, as `String`:

```
System.out.println(answer.toPlainString());
```

Keep in mind that `.toPlainString()` is required if you do want scientific notation.

And this of course could also be done in a one-liner.

As answered before: `BigInteger`s will also suffice for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger or BigDecimal will help you

```
BigInteger veryBigNumber = new BigInteger("9999999999999");
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, since you don't have floating point, you can use long. If this is not enough, BigInteger is your best bet.

If you do need the floating point, then use double or BigDecimal